# Como pegar id de um ImageView no android?

Tags: java, android

Como consigo pegar um id de uma imagem de um ImageView.
Exemplo, para eu setar uma imagem no meu ImageView eu uso o seguinte código.

> imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icone_x);

Como eu faço o processo inverso?
Por exemplo, quero receber um inteiro que referencia R.drawable.icone_x, queria mais ou menos isso.

> int resID = imageView.getImageResource();

Mas não existe esse método.

Comment: Juarez, não entendi muito bem sua pergunta. Você quer armazenar apenas o resID de um drawable em uma variável? Se for isso, o `R.drawable.icone_x` já faz esse trabalho para você!

Comment: Essa ImageView é dinamica, conforme o usuario clica ela muda de imagem, eu criei um listener e preciso saber qual imagem ela está mostrando no momento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [resposta do @PauloRodrigues](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38307/6436) é bem legal. Mas deixo minha sugestão, que seria extender o `ImageView`, adicionando o comportamento que você quer. É claro que involve um *refactoring* caso já esteja usando `ImageView's` em seu aplicativo, mas não involve adicionar mais código (que você pode esquecer) ao setar uma `tag` no `ImageView`.

A subclasse ficaria:

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

    private int mImageResource;

    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        this(context, attrs, 0, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

        // Recupera o id do resource setado no xml
        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, com.android.internal.R.styleable.ImageView, defStyleAttr, defStyle);
        mImageResource = a.getResourceId(com.android.internal.R.styleable.ImageView_src, 0);

        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageResource(int resId) {
        mImageResource = resId;
        super.setImageResource(resId);
    }

    public int getImageResource() {
        return mImageResource;
    }
}
```

O uso em xml seria parecido com os demais, apenas trocando `ImageView` por `nome.do.seu.pacote.CustomImageView`.

Comment: Verdade, no havia pensado nessa soluçao. Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Estou assumindo que sua intenção é obter um inteiro referenciando à sua imagem, mas isso não é o que realmente acontece quando você utiliza o método `setImageResource`. Você pode verificar em [`ImageView#setImageResource()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) o que o *Android* faz por trás, que é buscar um recurso que na maioria do caso é um `BitmapDrawable`, mas pode ser outro tipo, e então é aplicado ao `ImageView`.

A melhor solução para o seu caso acredito que seja guardar o nome ou a própria identificação em algum lugar para depois recuperar, por exemplo usando `setTag()`:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
imageView.setTag("image1");
```

E então você pode recuperá-lo assim:

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(imageView.getTag(), "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Claro, é uma suposição que depende de como você está querendo implantar.