# Como comparar Drawables?

Tags: android

Galera, é o seguinte... gostaria de saber como vejo se o arquivo que esta setado no ImageButton é igual a tal drawable.

Para ficar mais facil gostaria de fazer algo assim:

```
final ImageButton imgBt = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageSelect);

if(imgBt.getDrawable() == R.drawable.circle_blue) {
    //Executar Codigo
}
```

Mas assim nao da certo... alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Jeiferson, acho que não é possível, talvez haja uma forma. Mas fazendo uma subclasse do `ImageButton` por exemplo que saiba o `id` do Drawable daria certo, dê uma olhada nessa resposta para ver se ajuda a encontrar o caminho: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38283/como-pegar-id-de-um-imageview-no-android/38311#38311

Answer (score 0):

Jeiferson, um possível workaround seria setar uma tag no botão, onde a tag seria o id do drawable.

Exemplo:

```
meuLindoBotao.setTag(R.drawable.imagemAtual);    
int imagemDoMeuLindoBotao = (Integer) meuLindoBotao.getTag(); //vai retornar o id do drawable atual
```

Feito isso, você só precisaria comparar o id com o que você quiser!

Espero ter ajudado!