# Como comparar imagens "setadas" em Imagebuttons?

Tags: android

Pessoal como faço para comparar se o a imagem do drawable "setada" em um ImageButton é igual a null por exemplo, ou a outra Imagem contida em outro Imagebutton?

```
   ImageButton q1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.q1);
    ImageButton q2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.q2);
    ImageButton q3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.q3);


    if (q1.getDrawable() != null &&
            q2.getDrawable() != null &&
            q3.getDrawable() != null) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Teste 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (q1.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(q2.getDrawable().getConstantState()) &&
                q2.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(q3.getDrawable().getConstantState())) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Teste 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
```

Comment: Pode ser que [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38283/4337) te ajude em algo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [`getConstantState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.ConstantState.html) para verificar se dois *Drawable* são iguais.

*BitmapDrawables* criados a partir do mesmo *resource* partilham o mesmo *bitmap* guardado no seus *ConstantState*.

```
imgBt1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
imgBt2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

if(imgBt1.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(imgBt2.getDrawable().getConstantState())){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Imagem igual", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Imagem diferente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Para verificar se o o *ImageButton* tem associado um determinado *Drawable*:
<sub>Adaptado desta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13964990/2556111)</sub>

```
if(imgBt1.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(
          getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher).getConstantState())){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Imagem igual", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Imagem diferente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Para verificar se o ImageButton **não tem** imagem associada verifique se `getDrawable()` retorna `null`

```
if(imgBt1.getDrawable() == null){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Botão não tem imagem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Botão tem imagem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou, nada aconteceu

Comment: Como assim. Eu testei antes de postar. Edite a sua pergunta e coloque lá o código.

Comment: Qual é o `android:targetSdkVersion` da app?

Comment: 15 o target e o min em 4

Comment: OS botões q1, q2 e q3 têm imagens iguais?

Comment: Sim são, e tambem não caem no primeiro if

Comment: As imagens foram atribuidas aos *ImageButton* através do atributo `android:src=`?

Comment: Atribui pelo setBackgroundResource

Comment: Assim sendo substitua `getDrawable()` por `getBackground()`. No entanto aconselho a usar `setImageResource()` em vez de `setBackgroundResource()`.

Comment: Lembre-se que um *ImageButton* tem por defeito um *Backgroud* atribuído. Por isso julgo que `q1.getBackground() != null` será sempre `true`

Comment: Funcionou obrigado!