# Associar duas imagem

Tags: android, button

Queria criar uma `app` que ao clicar numa imagem mudasse a sua imagem e ficava aguardar para clicar em outra imagem. Caso as duas imagens fossem iguais (com os mesmo valor) ativa um botão que dava a possibilidade de passar para outro Layout.

Só tenho o código para alterar a imagem.

```
botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {         
    if( ????????? ) 
       botao.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.preto);                
    else
       botao.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.verde);

}
```

Comment: Não está claro o que pretende. No entanto, se o quer saber é se duas imagens(drawables) são iguais veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/61019/2541)

Comment: Quero associar duas imagens (como seja aqueles jogos que temos que clicar para descubrir as imagens  e so ficam a mostra quando sao iguas)

Comment: Você quer fazer um jogo da memória, certo?

Comment: Sim, era essa a minha ideia

Comment: isso.. é um jogo da memória...
na verdade a imagem é só "a casca" do problema. isso tem que ser feito com lógica de programação. Voce pode usar um arraylist com vinte membros, sendo 10 deles repetidos, e os embaralhe. aí é só preencher um "gridview" com o arraylist e quando clicar é só checar se são iguais.

Comment: Obrigado.Onde posso ler mais como fazer uma arraylist? ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Algoritmo

1. Crie uma matriz
2. Associe cada par (linha e coluna) a uma imagem
3. Em cada clique de imagem
       - Verifique se é o clique 1, se for troque a imagem
       - Se for clique 2, zerar o contador de click e verificar se as imagens são iguais. Caso sejam iguais, Mantenha as imagens virada. 
       - Verifique se ainda existe imagens a serem viradas/clicadas.

O algoritmo é este. Lembre de deixar a imagem sendo exibida por 3 segundos caso as 2 imagens virada **não** sejam iguais.